# why reducer is able to access the latest props?

Tags: reactjs

Please try this sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/7ypm405o8q

```
    function reducer(state, action) {
       if (action.type === 'tick') {
         return state + step;
       } else {
         throw new Error();
       }
    }

  useEffect(() => {

    const id = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'tick' });
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, [dispatch]);

    return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

My question is: think about this, at first, **step** in **Counter** component is 1, then timer is triggered and **tick action** is dispatched, at this time you change input to 11, you will find that: **step** in **reducer** function is 11, not 1. In my understanding, each render of component is like a snapshot. So when the aforementioned action is triggered, the **step** in the component (including effects, functions, everywhere) should be 1.

---

Let me rephrase my question: say the time interval is very small, like `1` (currently it's `1000`). Is it possible this scene happens: when you change input from `1` to `11`, you will see this sequence `state + 11`, then `state + 1` .

Comment: Components rerender when `state` **OR** `props` update, *and* your reducer is defined *inside* your component and redefined on *each* render cycle, using the current `step` value passed from props enclosed in its scope.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is your dispatch holds the reference to your latest `reducer` function, which has the latest `state`(step). Would recommend exploring more on closure.

To get what you are expecting, send the step count from the dispatch. Without adding `step` in dependency array (NOT RECOMMENDED), just for playing around.

```
dispatch({ type: 'tick', step });
```

Comment: **dispatch holds the reference to your latest reducer function** emm, interesting. Let me find other evidence for your point.

Answer (score 0):

Components rerender when `state` **OR** `props` update, *and* your reducer is defined *inside* your component, so it is redefined on *each* render cycle, using the current `step` value passed from props enclosed in it's scope.

You can add `step` to your state and dispatch an action to update it.

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  step: 1
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "tick": {
      const { count, step } = state;
      return { ...state, count: count + step };
    }

    case "updateStep": {
      const { step } = action;
      return { ...state, step };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Counter.js: add an effect hook to update the step when the `step` prop updates

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: "updateStep", step });
}, [step]);
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-flower-yjd2u]